# Database Query String URL

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am looking to parse some database information through a URL.  Im not sure how exactly to do it.

Each event entry listed at the bottom of the page should include a
hyperlink that will take the administrator to a new web form for recording results for that event. The
EventID is passed via a query string parameter, e.g. `RecordResults.php?EventID=4`.

How exactly would I go about doing this?

Thanks for your help!
Cheers

Comment: This is _very_ broad.  Essentially, on your `RecordResults.php` page you would read in the value from `$_GET["EventID"]` (check that the value exists before trying to use it, validate that it's numeric, sanitize it before putting it in a SQL query, etc.) and then use that value when querying your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this in **RecordResults.php**:

```
// Get id from URL
$id = mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['EventID'] );

// If id is number
if( (int)$id == $id && (int)$id > 0 ) {

     // Database connection and select database
     $link = mysql_connect('localhost','db_username','db_password')
     mysql_select_db('db_name', $link);

     // Get record from database
     $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE EventID=' . $id;
     $result = mysql_query( $sql, $link );    
     $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );

     // Show record with HTML here 
     print_r( $row );

} else {

   echo "Record not found";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that Naveed Perfect! Another quick question, How would I link a piece of text for the specified ID. Like View Results with a link to a specific Event ID

Comment: something like this: `<a href='RecordResults.php?EventID=4'>View Result For Event ID 4</a>`

Answer (score 0):

In your `RecordResults.php` file you need to check for the `$_GET` parameters and construct an SQL query to retrieve the desired database rows. Build your HTML around the results and output it to the browser.

Don't forget to sanitize the GET parameters to prevent SQL injection.